# Can we restrict resource level access with scopes in SMART on FHIR using Azure API for FHIR

Tags: fhir-server-for-azure, smart-on-fhir

We recently started exploring FHIR and we are using Azure API for FHIR with SMART on FHIR enabled. We would like to restrict access given to a SMART app (SPA) when a SMART app asks for permissions from a FHIR API. In [this](https://github.com/microsoft/fhir-server/tree/master/samples/apps/SmartLauncher) sample, we have updated the scope in the request to "patient/Practitioner.read" in wwwroot/sampleapp/launch.html file, something like below

```
{
FHIR.oauth2.authorize({
"client_id": <client-Id>,
"scope": "patient/Practitioner.read", 
"redirect_uri": <SMART-App-URI>
})
}
```

Though the client app requested for specific scope like "patient/Practitioner.read", the app is able to fetch all the other resources from the Azure API for FHIR.[This](https://github.com/microsoft/fhir-server/blob/master/docs/Roles.md) document says, currently only root level scopes are supported. But we like to know if there is a way to achieve resource level scope restriction using Azure API for FHIR.

Comment: We're facing the same issue, did you find a solution in the meantime?